# How to convert 1 to true in markup for ng-model assignment?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

This is my current `ng-repeat` code:

```
<li ng-repeat="tik in settingsModel.port_tickers">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tik.alert" name="tik.ticker" value="tik.ticker">
    <p>{{ tik.ticker }}</p>
</li>
```

This is what a single `tik` object from `settingsModel.port_tickers` looks like:

```
{
    alert: 1,
    ticker: $TEST,
    user_id: 66
}
```

I'm getting either `1` or `0` back from the server, is there an easy way to filter this in the markup? Without having to use some kind of loop to convert `1`s and `0`s into `true` or `false`?

Comment: Can you explain the problem more?  you are getting 1 or 0 back from the server as the response or for the tik.alert?

Comment: Yes I'm getting objects back from the server with `alert` set to either `1` or `0` I need the ng-model in the markup to reflect this, but it only works with `true` or `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to use `ng-true-value="1"` and `ng-false-value="0"` attributes. Check more at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to change it to true/false.  Just update the checkbox markup.
It also seems like ticker and alert are the same thing.

```
<li ng-repeat="tik in fsc.settingsModel.port_tickers">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tik.alert" name="tik.ticker" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" value="tik.ticker">
    <p>{{ tik.alert }}</p>    <p>{{ tik.ticker }}</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your usage !! can be a handy shortcut.

!!0 > !true > false
!!1 > !false > true